# Flutter: How to set up a screen rotation listener

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any way to listen for Screen orientation -- the time when screen is being rotated not when the screen is full rotated (`OrientationBuilder` does the job in this case).

---

**Code**

```
class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
  static Widget _portrait = Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(height: 240, color: Colors.blue),
      Container(height: 240, color: Colors.red),
    ],
  );

  Widget _landscape = Center(child: FlutterLogo(size: 200));
  Widget _child = _portrait;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: OrientationBuilder(builder: (_, orientation) {
        if (orientation == Orientation.portrait)
          _child = _portrait;
        else
          _child = _landscape;

        return AnimatedSwitcher(
          duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
          child: _child,
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

---

**Output:**

[image]

---

**Problem**

As you can see when screen is rotated from Portrait to Landscape I get overflow error, this is because of `AnimatedSwitcher`, if I use `seconds: 0` in `duration`, there is no error. Is there any way to listen for screen rotation change, so that I can set `seconds` to `0`? Or any other solution which lets me use `AnimatedSwitcher` without causing overflow issue.

---

**Note:**

I'm not looking for workaround like, use `Wrap` instead of `Column`, what's the need of using `AnimatedSwitcher` etc. The app I am working on requires it to be as it is, I just created an easy to reproduce repo to reflect my code. Thank you

Comment: no, there is no such listener

Comment: @pskink I wish there had been a one...

Comment: if there is no such listener i think there is no such need for it: `OrientationBuilder` is good enough

Comment: @pskink I agree with you mate, but I'm not able to solve it using `OrientationBuilder`.

Comment: if you have overflow yellow-black error use some sort of scroll view like `SingleChildScrollView` for example

Answer (score 0):

Wrap body content into SingleChildScrollView

```
class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
  static Widget _portrait = Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(height: 240, color: Colors.blue),
      Container(height: 240, color: Colors.red),
    ],
  );

  Widget _landscape = Center(child: FlutterLogo(size: 200));
  Widget _child = _portrait;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView (
        child: OrientationBuilder(builder: (_, orientation) {
          if (orientation == Orientation.portrait)
            _child = _portrait;
          else
            _child = _landscape;

          return AnimatedSwitcher(
            duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
            child: _child,
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```